# How to call another page using telerik:GridViewDynamicHyperlinkColumn?

Tags: c#, windows, telerik

Im very new in programming and my question is probably very easy, but i couldnt find the right way to search.

I have a Windows Application with this grid:

```
            <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RelatorioEtapaProdutiva}"
                             Style="{DynamicResource BaseRadGridMetroStyle}"
                             IsFilteringAllowed="False"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,5,10">
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=cliente}" Header="CLIENTE"/>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=aplicacao}" Header="APLICAÇÃO"/>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=data}" DataFormatString="{} {0:dd/MM/yyyy}" Header="DATA" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDynamicHyperlinkColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=operador}"  Header="OPERADOR"  />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=departamento}" Header="DEPARTAMENTO" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=etapa}" Header="ETAPA PRODUTIVIDADE" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=total}" Header="TOTAL" />
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
```

The Column "Operador" should show the name of the users and be a link which i can click and send me to another xaml page with the detail of that user. I could do the link using "GridViewDynamicHyperlinkColumn", but i cant figure it out how to redirect me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `NavigateUrlFormatString` property of the `GridViewDynamicHyperlinkColumn`

Reference:  [Telerik Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radgridview/columns/columntypes/column-types-dynamic-hyperlink-column)

Comment: I have already tried to use this property, but i could not figure it out how to redirect to another view.xaml. Its a console application.

Comment: Not sure I follow. You say "Windows Application" above but "Console Application" here.  Which is which?  I've never heard of using a Telerik GridView in a Console Application.  What have you tried?  Maybe post some more code or explain exactly what you are trying to do more thoroughly.